# Terraform: length() on data source cannot be determined until apply?

Tags: amazon-web-services, terraform

I am trying to dynamically declare multiple `aws_nat_gateway` data sources by retrieving the list of public subnets through the `aws_subnet_ids` data source. However, when I try to set the `count` parameter to be equal to the length of the subnet IDs, I get an error saying `The "count" value depends on resource attributes that cannot be determined until apply...`.

This is almost in direct contradiction to the [example in their documentation](https://www.terraform.io/docs/providers/aws/d/subnet_ids.html)!. How do I fix this? Is their documentation wrong?

I am using Terraform v0.12.

```
data "aws_vpc" "environment_vpc" {
  id = var.vpc_id
}

data "aws_subnet_ids" "public_subnet_ids" {
  vpc_id = data.aws_vpc.environment_vpc.id
  tags = {
    Tier = "public"
  }
  depends_on = [data.aws_vpc.environment_vpc]
}

data "aws_nat_gateway" "nat_gateway" {
  count      = length(data.aws_subnet_ids.public_subnet_ids.ids)  # <= Error
  subnet_id  = data.aws_subnet_ids.public_subnet_ids.ids.*[count.index]
  depends_on = [data.aws_subnet_ids.public_subnet_ids]
}
```

I expect to be able to apply this template successfully, but I am getting the following error:

```
Error: Invalid count argument

  on ../src/variables.tf line 78, in data "aws_nat_gateway" "nat_gateway":
  78:   count      = "${length(data.aws_subnet_ids.public_subnet_ids.ids)}"

The "count" value depends on resource attributes that cannot be determined
until apply, so Terraform cannot predict how many instances will be created.
To work around this, use the -target argument to first apply only the
resources that the count depends on.
```

Comment: What command(s) are you executing to cause this error?

Comment: `terraform apply`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems you are trying to fetch subnets that weren't created yet or they couldn't be determinated, the terraform cmd output suggests you add -target flag to create the VPC and subnets or do another task first, after that, you'll apply the nat_gateway resource. I suggest you use the AZs list instead of subnets ids, I'll add a simple example below.

```
variable "vpc_azs_list" {
  default = [
    "us-east-1d",
    "us-east-1e"
  ]
}

resource "aws_nat_gateway" "nat" {
  count         = var.enable_nat_gateways ? length(var.azs_list) : 0
  allocation_id = "xxxxxxxxx"
  subnet_id     = "xxxxxxxxx"
  depends_on = [
    aws_internet_gateway.main,
    aws_eip.nat_eip,
  ]
  tags = {
    "Name"       = "nat-gateway-name"
    "costCenter" = "xxxxxxxxx"
    "owner"      = "xxxxxxxxx"
  }
}
```

I hope will be useful to you and other users.